# block level replication - perserve NTFS permissions?

Tags: replication, ntfs

When doing block level replication between 2 drives (with a NTFS partition) on separate but identical Windows installations, do the file/folder permissions get preserved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...do the file/folder permissions get
>   preserved?

Yes, of course. It's a *block level copy*. Meta-data, like permissions, are blocks just like files.

Comment: One IT guy of our client just told us this: "[IBM PPRC] will not copy the folder permission from Production to DR servers". Just want to verify. Anyway, how do different Windows systems read/parse the SID metadata? Wouldn't each system has its own SID <-> user mappings?

Comment: The old permissions might well be copied but that doesn't mean they'll be understood by the new system - or I should say the new/target system will understand them perfectly well, it just won't know what to do with them if they're local account SIDs from the old machine.

Comment: @Robert brings up a good point. If all the ACLs are from your AD domain, you should be fine. If they're local users, though, the "receiving" system will not be able to resolve the SIDs.